# Does a MySQL dump that contains triggers double data on import?

Tags: trigger, mysqldump, mariadb-10.2

I have a quick and simple question to clarify. I have medium sized database (400 Gigs) running in MariaDB 10.2 with lots of tables and lots of triggers as well. I am planning to take  a mysqldump and import it to another server. So when we take mysqldump, it will be packed with triggers by default as well.

So if I import that dump with triggers to another server, do those triggers fire during the import and create duplicate data?

I know we can take dump without triggers, but I am asking if I import dump with triggers does this create data duplication?

Comment: Why not do a test with a small sample database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take time to run `mysqldump`, even with all default arguments, you will see that triggers in the dump file are created *after* all `insert` statements that populate your tables. So no, there will be no duplication, your data after restoring the dump will be the same as in the source database.

Comment: I had this thought and you confirmed it and it does makes sense.